# Running an app build with very old iOS SDK on a device running current iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, development

I have 2 iOS devices, an iPhone 6s, and an iPhone 4. I'm currently using OS X Mavericks 10.9.0 and plan on using Xcode.

The iPhone 6s is running iOS 12.2, and iPhone 4 is running iOS 7. My Xcode version is 5.1.0.

Will I be able to deploy an app using Xcode 5 on my iPhone 6s?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but I expect you'll have so many problems that it won't be worth it.  Xcode 5.1 doesn't know anything about iOS 12.2 so you'll probably have many compatibility errors, if it works at all.  iOS 12.2 doesn't even run well (or at all) on Xcode 9 so I would doubt it works with 5.1.

Comment: Not sure whether it works?

Comment: Actually, I'm developing for ios 7 and my phone had ios 12.2

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please re-check the version of iOS running on your iPhone 4. The last available version of iOS for iPhone 4 is iOS 7.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 5.1.0 include iOS 7.1 SDK. You cannot debug an app build with this Xcode/iOS SDK combination on your iPhone 6s running iOS 12.2 (iOS 12 was non-existent when Xcode 5.1 was released and Xcode is not aware of it).

You can however, in-theory generate the app IPA and deploy it on iOS 12. iOS 11 and later require your app to have executable support for 64-bit mode. So you need to make sure to build your iOS app with 64-bit mode.

However, you may end up hitting roadblocks as iOS 7 is ancient in terms of how iOS has evolved. With a decently complex app, you may run into issues when running an app built with much older SDK on a device running current iOS.